# SQL: perform undersampling to select a subset of majority class

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sampling

I have a table that looks like the following:

| user_id | target |
| --- | --- |
| 1278 | 1 |
| 9809 | 0 |
| 3345 | 0 |
| 9800 | 0 |
| 1298 | 1 |
| 1223 | 0 |

My goal is to perform undersampling which means that I want to randomly select a subset of users that have a target of 0 while keeping all users that have a target of 1 value. I have tried the following code, however, since the user_ids are all unique, it doesn't remove the rows with the target of 0 randomly. Any idea what I need to do?

```
select *
from (select user_id, target, row_number() over (partition by user_id, target order by rand()) as seq
from dataset.mytable
) a
where target = 1 or seq = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.* except (seqnum, cnt1)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by target order by rand()) as seqnum,
             countif(target = 1) over () as cnt1
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= cnt1;
```

The above might have performance problems -- or even exceed resources because of the large volume of data being sorted.  An approximate method might also work for your purposes:

```
select t.* except (cnt, cnt1)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by target) as cnt,
             countif(target = 1) over () as cnt1
      from t
     ) t
where rand() < cnt * 1.0 / cnt1;
```

This is not guaranteed to produce exactly the same numbers of `0` and `1`, but the numbers will be quite close.

Comment: thanks for you help. I tried the second code and the first mentioned that I should have used group by and once I grouped by all, I ran it and it gave me the division by 0 error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach - it leaves all target=1 rows and ~50% of target=0 rows

```
select * 
from `dataset.mytable`
where if(target = 1, true, rand() < 0.5)
```